# What is $Q(x)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field

I do not really understand what $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ is here:

[image]

Ofcourse we see that $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ is a field. But I have to "guesses" of what they mean, is one of them correct?

1.
$\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ consists of $a_n\pi^n \ldots +a_1\pi+a_0, a_i \in \mathbb{Q}$

2.$\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ consists of $\frac{a_n\pi^n...+a_0}{b_m\pi^n +a_0}$.Where the a's and b's are rational.

In either way $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ is a set of real numbers, that can be written as a comnation of rational numbers and $\pi$?

The reason I am unclear, is that I don't really see how they use case 2 in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second guess is a correct description of $\Bbb Q(\pi)$ (as long as you specify that the denominator is not the zero polynomial).  The first guess describes the ring $\Bbb Q[\pi]$, which does not have inverses.  In particular, $\pi$ has no inverse since $\pi f(\pi) \ne 0$ for any polynomial $f\in \Bbb Q[x]$.  It's not hard to see that these rational functions in $\pi$ form the smallest subfield of $\Bbb C$ (or $\Bbb R$) which contains $\pi$ and $\Bbb Q.

Here, the key is that $\Bbb Q(\pi)$ is **isomorphic** to $\Bbb Q(x)$ as fields, they're not the same thing per se.  The application of Case 2 is that $\Bbb Q(\pi)$ is the field of fractions of $\Bbb Q[\pi]$, and so in this case that evaluation map $\Bbb Q(x) \to \Bbb Q(\pi)$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: When you say that $Q(x)$ and $Q(\pi)$ are isomorpic, they are this because $Q(x)$ consists of $\frac{a_nx^n+..a_1x+a_0}{b_nx^n+..+b_1x+b_0}$, while $Q(\pi)$ is consists of $\frac{a_n\pi^n+..a_1\pi+a_0}{b_n\pi^n+..+b_1\pi+b_0}$, so we just change $\pi$ and x in each expression, but also $Q(x)$ is a field of polynomials, but $Q(\pi)$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$? Can you confirm this?

Comment: This is a concrete description of the isomorphism, yes.  You can't say anything more that isomorphism since they are not defined to be the same sets.

Comment: Thanks, it get's really confusing when they build layer after layer of structures.

Answer (score 0):

It is your second option. The first is called $\Bbb Q[\pi]$. In the example they make $F=\Bbb Q$ and $\alpha=\pi$.

Comment: So if I have a polynomial in $(\mathbb{Q}(\pi))[x]$. It is a polynomial that looks like this $a_n x^2 +..1+a_1x+a_0$, where each $a_i$ is of the form $\frac{b_m\pi^n+...+b_1\pi+b_0}{c_k\pi^k+..+c_1\pi+c_0}$, where all the a's and b's are rational, and ofcourse the denominator is not zero?